# Clear the PendingFileRenameOperations registry value

Tags: batch-file, registry

One of my troubleshooting steps is to clear the `PendingFileRenameOperations` registry value to avoid rebooting a server.

What I would like to do is clear this through a batch file, I don't want to delete it, just clear it.

It's the following registry value

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Session Manager/PendingFileRenameOperations
```

Answer (score 3):

The command

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe add "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager" /v PendingFileRenameOperations /t REG_MULTI_SZ /d "" /f
```

replaces current value of multi-string value `PendingFileRenameOperations` with an empty string.

The path you wrote in the question does not exist on my Windows 7 x64 machine.

For details on command **reg** open a command prompt window and run there first `reg /?` and second `reg add /?`

But why clearing this registry value used to delete or replace (usually update) files after reboot before Windows loads drivers and starts processes and applications should avoid rebooting a Windows server is beyond my understanding.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I shall try that tonight or tomorrow. I work with backups on a huge scale, if there is anything in there(in that registry) relating to the software we use, it can sometimes throw up errors and the backup will fail. This is how we avoid rebooting a customer box :)

Answer (score 2):

Some software just checks for the key existence and doesn't care if its blank,So For deleting Key,Use My Way :

```
reg delete "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager" /v PendingFileRenameOperations /f
```

Comment: Hello there, I don't think OP really wants to delete the record, even if some tools verify if the record exists. This will wipe out the registry from the system.